# FLASK: Serving file to browser behind API proxy

Tags: python, api, proxy, flask

When the user enters `http://example2.com:5500/?param=x` the code below generates a data.csv file and serves it to the browser. It works perfectly like this.

However, I have deployed it behind an API proxy, so that the user makes a call to `http://example1.com/?param=x` which is internally transformed into `http://example2.com:5500/?param=x`.

As a result, instead of serving data.csv to the browser as before, it displays on the browser all the data.csv content. The view source-code feature shows exactly what data.csv should contain, without any HTML headers, just the data.csv content, but it is not being served as attachement. Any ideas?

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def get_file():

    alldata = []

    while len(new_data) > 0:
            new_data = api.timeline(max_id=oldest)
            alldata.extend(new_data)
            oldest = alldata[-1].id - 1    

    outdata = ""
    for data in alldata:
            outdata += ",".join(data) + "\n"

    response = make_response(outdata)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=data.csv"

    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host = app.config['HOST'], port = app.config['PORT'])
```

**EDIT: Included mapping code to transform request to example1.com to example2.com (secret_url)**

```
# This is example1.com
@app.route("/api/<projectTitle>/<path:urlSuffix>", methods=['GET'])
def projectTitlePage(projectTitle, urlSuffix):

    projectId = databaseFunctions.getTitleProjectId(projectTitle)
    projectInfo = databaseFunctions.getProjectInfo(projectId)
    redirectionQueryString = re.sub('apikey=[^&]+&?', '', request.query_string).rstrip('&')
    redirectionUrl = projectInfo['secretUrl'].rstrip('/')
    if urlSuffix is not None:
        redirectionUrl += '/' + urlSuffix.rstrip('/')
    redirectionUrl += '/?' + redirectionQueryString
    redirectionHeaders = request.headers

    print request.args.to_dict(flat=False)
    try:
        r = requests.get(redirectionUrl, data=request.args.to_dict(flat=False), headers=redirectionHeaders)
    except Exception, e:
        return '/error=Error: bad secret url: ' + projectInfo.get('secretUrl')

    return r.text
```

Comment: The proxy must be modifying the headers in the response. You can compare the HTTP response from the app with the response you get from the proxy in the browser's debugger. That should give you an idea of where the problem is.

Comment: Yes Miguel, the HTTP response that I get from the proxy has no headers at all. It is like trying to open data.csv from a browser.

Comment: What proxy server is this?

Comment: It is not really a proxy server, it is just a mapping of the "secret url" http://example2.com:5500/?param=x with the public one http://example1.com/?param=x. So that every time we receive a call with example1 we transform it to example2:5500. I think the problem is that example2 returns data.csv as attachment to example1, but example1 cannot forward this again as attachment to the browser.

Comment: I'd like to know what software are you using to do this "mapping", and how do you have it configured.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I have included that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your homegrown proxy is not returning headers back to the application. Try this:

```
@app.route("/api/<projectTitle>/<path:urlSuffix>", methods=['GET'])
def projectTitlePage(projectTitle, urlSuffix):

    # ...

    return r.text, r.status_code, r.headers
```